# this.dialog(“close”) not working when passed as function

Tags: jquery, dialog

Here is my issue:

I have 2 variable:

```
var func = function() {
   $(dialog).dialog("close");
}

var m = "hello"
```

and I call a method

```
this.xyz(func , m)
```

Method xyz looks like

```
xyz : function(func, m) {
   //there is an OK button on which I am calling click event
   click: function() {
         func();
   }
}
```

Approach-1
Now inside xyz if I replace **func();** with **$(dialog).dialog("close");** works perfect

Approach-2
but with func(); button click will not close the dialog box

I want to use the approach 2 but cant make it work

thnx

Comment: What error message do you get? Can you make a basic example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass the variable and it worked

```
xyz : function(func, m) {
 //there is an OK button on which I am calling click event
 click: func 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're forgetting that new scope will lose `this`, you have to [**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [**apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) your new function.

```
xyz : function(func, m) {
   //there is an OK button on which I am calling click event
   click: function() {
         func.apply(this);
   }
}
```